# Retrofit POST with a json object containing parameters

Tags: android, json, gson, retrofit

I'm using Retrofit to send a  `POST` request to my server:

```
@POST("/login")
void login( @Body User user ,Callback<User> callback);
```

Where my `user` object has only `email` and `password` fields.

Checking the logs, I can see that my parameters are sent with this format:

```
D/Retrofit﹕{"email":"example@test.com","password":"asdfasdf"}
```

What I need to do to my parameters be sent like this?

```
{"user" :  {"email":"example@test.com","password":"asdfasdf"} }
```

Comment: i also want to create same jsonrequest using retrofit like below

     {
        "params":{"email":"nilhr@gamil.com","password":"ni1234","firstName":"Nilesh","lastName":"Aher"}}

Can you give me piece of code

Answer (score 7, accepted):

EDIT: Making the right way, using a custom `JsonSerializer`:

```
public class CustomGsonAdapter {
    public static class UserAdapter implements JsonSerializer<User> {
        public JsonElement serialize(User user, Type typeOfSrc,
                                     JsonSerializationContext context) {
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            JsonElement je = gson.toJsonTree(user);
            JsonObject jo = new JsonObject();
            jo.add("user", je);
            return jo;
        }
    }
}
```

And then, on your API Client builder:

```
public static RestApiClient buildApiService() {
    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
            .setFieldNamingPolicy(FieldNamingPolicy.LOWER_CASE_WITH_UNDERSCORES)
            .registerTypeAdapter(User.class, new CustomGsonAdapter.UserAdapter())
            .create();

    RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
            .setEndpoint(API_URL)
            .setConverter(new GsonConverter(gson))
            .build();
    return restAdapter.create(MudamosApi.class);
}
```

Comment: Can you please paste your code where you actually make the login call, How are you passing in User object?

Comment: Hi @Noble6, The format is that last line of code in my comment, but I learned the right way, using a custom gson converter
https://square.github.io/retrofit/#restadapter-configuration
But thanks for asking!

Comment: @KayanAlmeida I'm looking to do the exact same thing. Do you have any sample code of how you did this using your custom converter?

Comment: @KayanAlmeida Tremendous. Thanks!

Comment: This is definitely the way to go! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The simplest mode to solve your problem is creating a RequestPOJO class, for example:

File User.java:

```
public class User{
    public String email;
    public String password;
}
```

File LoginRequestPojo.java:

```
public class LoginRequestPojo{
    public User user;

    public LoginRequestPojo(User user){
        this.user = user;
    }
}
```

And, in your retrofit 2 request:

```
@POST("/login")
void login( @Body LoginRequestPojo requestPojo, Callback<User> callback);
```

Finally, your request body:

`{"user":{"email":"someone@something.com","password":"123123"`}}

Comment: I've done that before, if you check my answer before edition was similar to yours, but it is not the recommended way, since it creates a `class` that does almost nothing. A better approach is to centralize all JSON related handling inside a `GsonAdapter`, or maybe use Jackson with annotations too! :)

Comment: Aren't you creating a class to solve the problem either way?  Why is a more complex class to solve the same problem the better approach?